# How can i draw my own route in google map android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, routes, location

[This is the code i have done to implement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr6gx.png)I need to implement an application, where i need to add my own route in google map. I have tried it with direction API but it draw like this.[Image which draw route like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xju6L.png)

I only need to draw a single poly line on road on my way. So please suggest me a better way that how can i implement it.

Comment: visit this https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
public void addPolylineToMap(GoogleMap map, List<LatLng> route) {
    final PolylineOptions polyline = new PolylineOptions();

    for (LatLng point : route) {
        polyline.add(point);
    }

    polyline.width(5)
            .color(Color.RED);

    map.addPolyline(polyline);
}
```

Comment: I have already did it in my code, but this doesn't work. You can check the screenshot.

Comment: also make sure that you are updating the map in `public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map)` method